# How to load data from xlsx - javafx

Tags: javafx, apache-poi, tableview, xlsx

Can someone help me at creat code ?
I starting at Java, at next step i want create data at xlsx file.
Plan:
Whan I open aplication thane data from xlsx will automatically import to table.
Whan i add new row to table this row will bee add to xlsx file.

Controller:

```
package sample.Controllers;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import sample.Utils.StopLista;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class StopController implements Initializable {




    @FXML
    private TableView<StopLista> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> dateColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> orderColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> modelColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> changeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> timeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> personColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<StopLista, String> commentsColumn;


    @FXML
    TextField dateText;
    @FXML
    TextField orderText;
    @FXML
    TextField modelText;
    @FXML
    TextField changeText;
    @FXML
    TextField timeText;
    @FXML
    TextField personText;
    @FXML
    TextField commentsText;

    public StopController() {
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("data"));
        orderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("zlecenie"));
        modelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("model"));
        changeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("zmiana"));
        timeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("czas"));
        personColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("osoba"));
        commentsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<StopLista, String>("uwagi"));
        tableView.setItems(addList());



        tableView.setEditable(true);
        dateColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        orderColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        modelColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        changeColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        timeColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        personColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        commentsColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());


    }

    public void addRowToTable() {
        StopLista nowyRekord = new StopLista(dateText.getText(), orderText.getText(), modelText.getText(),
                changeText.getText(), timeText.getText(), personText.getText(), commentsText.getText());
        tableView.getItems().add(nowyRekord);


        dateText.clear();
        orderText.clear();
        modelText.clear();
        changeText.clear();
        timeText.clear();
        personText.clear();
        commentsText.clear();
    }

    public void delateRowTable() {
        ObservableList<StopLista> wybranyRekord, wszystkieRekordy;
        try {
            wszystkieRekordy = tableView.getItems();
            if (wszystkieRekordy.size() != 0) {
                wybranyRekord = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
                wybranyRekord.forEach(wszystkieRekordy::remove);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //tabela jest pusta - nic się nie dzieje
        }

    }

    public ObservableList<StopLista> addList() {
        ObservableList<StopLista> orderList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();





        return orderList;
    }

    public void editData(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmDaty = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmDaty.setData(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }

    public void editOrder(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmZlecenia = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmZlecenia.setZlecenie(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }

    public void editModel(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmModelu = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmModelu.setModel(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }

    public void editChange(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmZmiany = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmZmiany.setZmiana(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }

    public void editTime(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmCzasu = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmCzasu.setCzas(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }

    public void editPerson(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmOsoby = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmOsoby.setOsoba(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }

    public void editComments(TableColumn.CellEditEvent cellEditEvent){
        StopLista zmUwag = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        zmUwag.setUwagi(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().toString());


    }





}
```

getters setters and controllers

```
package sample.Utils;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class StopLista {

    private SimpleStringProperty data, zlecenie, model, zmiana, czas, osoba, uwagi;

    public StopLista(String data, String zlecenie, String model,
                     String zmiana, String czas, String osoba,
                     String uwagi) {
        this.data = new SimpleStringProperty(data);
        this.zlecenie = new SimpleStringProperty(zlecenie);
        this.model = new SimpleStringProperty(model);
        this.zmiana = new SimpleStringProperty(zmiana);
        this.czas = new SimpleStringProperty(czas);
        this.osoba = new SimpleStringProperty(osoba);
        this.uwagi = new SimpleStringProperty(uwagi);
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty dataProperty() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data.set(data);
    }

    public String getZlecenie() {
        return zlecenie.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty zlecenieProperty() {
        return zlecenie;
    }

    public void setZlecenie(String zlecenie) {
        this.zlecenie.set(zlecenie);
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty modelProperty() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model.set(model);
    }

    public String getZmiana() {
        return zmiana.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty zmianaProperty() {
        return zmiana;
    }

    public void setZmiana(String zmiana) {
        this.zmiana.set(zmiana);
    }

    public String getCzas() {
        return czas.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty czasProperty() {
        return czas;
    }

    public void setCzas(String czas) {
        this.czas.set(czas);
    }

    public String getOsoba() {
        return osoba.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty osobaProperty() {
        return osoba;
    }

    public void setOsoba(String osoba) {
        this.osoba.set(osoba);
    }

    public String getUwagi() {
        return uwagi.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty uwagiProperty() {
        return uwagi;
    }

    public void setUwagi(String uwagi) {
        this.uwagi.set(uwagi);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me or show how to do this ?

Comment: I personally don't like to use TableView's edit table cell. What I do is use a button (Add new StopLista) to open a popup form that allows users to enter data for a table row. The form has a cancel and an add button. Once the user enter's the correct info the add button is enabled. The user can then click the button to add new data to the tableView and Excel file.

Comment: Can you show how to do This or add materials where I can read about this technics?

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo app that uses a button to open a popup window that allows new Persons to be entered. It also has a demo of how to do it without a popup window. For deleting, I only show one way. You can use the delete button to delete a person from the table only if a row is selected in the table. I also like to use Context menus on the selected row to delete from tables. I did not show that here.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource("primary.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PrimaryController implements Initializable{

    @FXML TableView<Person> tvPerson;
    @FXML TableColumn<Person, String> tcFirstName, tcLastName;
    @FXML Button btnAddNewPerson2;
    @FXML TextField tfFirstName, tfLastName;

    ObservableList<Person> obsPerson = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        tcFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        tcLastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList();
        persons.add(new Person("John", "Doe"));
        persons.add(new Person("Jane", "Doe"));

        obsPerson.addAll(persons);
        tvPerson.setItems(obsPerson);

        //Bind button to the textfields text properties
        btnAddNewPerson2.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.isEmpty(tcFirstName.textProperty())
                .or(Bindings.isEmpty(tfLastName.textProperty()))
        );

        btnAddNewPerson2.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
            obsPerson.add(new Person(tfFirstName.getText(), tfLastName.getText()));
        });
    }



    @FXML
    private void handleBtnAddNewPerson(ActionEvent event){
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        //Create Nodes to be used in popup
        TextField ltfFirstName = new TextField();
        ltfFirstName.setPromptText("Enter First Name");
        TextField ltfLastName = new TextField();
        ltfLastName.setPromptText("Enter Last Name");
        Button lbtnAddNewPerson = new Button("Add");
        lbtnAddNewPerson.setOnAction((t) -> {
            //Handle updating Excel file and tableview here!
            obsPerson.add(new Person(ltfFirstName.getText(), ltfLastName.getText()));
        });
        lbtnAddNewPerson.requestFocus();//Give this button focus

        //Bind add button to textfield text property
        lbtnAddNewPerson.disableProperty().bind(
            Bindings.isEmpty(ltfFirstName.textProperty())
                .or(Bindings.isEmpty(ltfLastName.textProperty()))
        );
        //Use to cancel
        Button lbtnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
        lbtnCancel.setOnAction((t) -> {
            stage.close();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(ltfFirstName, ltfLastName, lbtnAddNewPerson, lbtnCancel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("Add New Person");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initOwner(((Stage)((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()));
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnDeletePerson(ActionEvent event) {
        if(tvPerson.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null)
        {
            obsPerson.remove(tvPerson.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
        else{
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("You need to select a Person to delete!");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="396.0" prefWidth="619.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sed.test.mavenfxmltestingground.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tvPerson" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tcFirstName" prefWidth="290.0" text="First Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tcLastName" prefWidth="287.0" text="Last Name" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button fx:id="btnAddNewPerson" onAction="#handleBtnAddNewPerson" text="Add New Person" />
      <Button fx:id="btnDeletePerson" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBtnDeletePerson" text="Delete Person" />
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="tfFirstName" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="tfLastName" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <Button fx:id="btnAddNewPerson2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Person" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Ok i understand but on this option, when i close the application my new row will be not add. I need somethings where i can save chages.

Comment: @Happy You have to update your Excel file when you update the tableview.